# How to include/link css (and html) from sub directories?

Tags: html, css, apache

I've set up a very simple web page with some css files and a few html include files that were given to me by someone else.

The directory tree on my server looks like this:

`css/
  global.css
  site.css
includes/
  header.html
  footer.html
  nav.html
index.html
subdir/
  index.html`

All of my html files (except the ones in the `includes` directory) have this kind of stuff in it (among other things)

`...
<link href="css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<body>
  <!--#include file="includes/header.html" />
  ...
</body>
...`

This setup works fine with the top level `index.html` page that I have, but fails with anything else (i.e., `subdir/index.html`). I get a message in the browser that says:

```
[an error occurred while processing this directive]
```

I know that the apache web server just can't find the css and include files (I've checked the logs), but I don't know where to tell it to look for them. I've tried something like this:

```
<link href="../css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

but it doesn't work either.

I am really new at web programming so I apologize if this is overly basic stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want something like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/global.css" />
```

You start the path with an "/" to indicate the root followed by the exact path of the file when you are calling it from within a sub-directory or without the "/" when the the file is within the same directory as the html file.

You may find out more [here](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)